# tabs.getCurrent() result is undefined?

Tags: javascript, tabs, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

Not sure why I cannot retrieve info about current tab using getCurrent() when I navigate to, say, amazon.com or google.com and hit the browser icon for a browser action. Any hints on what I am missing?

MANIFEST:

```
{
  "name": "testGetCurrentTab",
  "version":  "1.0",
  "description":  "",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon/icon-32.png"
  },

  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }      
}
```

BACKGROUND:

```
function displayInfo() {

  function onGot(tabInfo) {
    console.log('Inside onGot() ...');
    console.log(tabInfo);
  }

  function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
  }

  var gettingCurrent = browser.tabs.getCurrent();
  gettingCurrent.then(onGot, onError);
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(displayInfo);
```

Here is the output:

```
Inside onGot() ...  background.js:4:7

undefined  background.js:5:7
```

Firefox Dev Edition 54  (64bit)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent

Comment: what is tabInfo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From MDN [`tabs.getCurrent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent):

> Get a [tabs.Tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) containing information about the tab that this script is running in.
>
> You can call this function in contexts where there is a browser tab, such as an [options page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Options_pages). If you call it from a background script or a popup, it will return undefined.

The `browserAction.onClicked` event returns the active tab, you do not need another API call.

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 console.log(tab)
})
```

See the [`tab` parameter for `browserAction.onClicked` listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked#Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. I actually had been trying to use getCurrent with a content script, but still getting undefined. I switched to background script for posting the question here, and in the process forgot that it won't work in a background script. It seems the contexts in which it can be used are very limited.

Comment: so What's the solution ? i didnt found example demo code of tabs.getCurrent in internet so far...

Comment: "This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup."

Answer (score 19):

You can get the currently active tab in the `background.js` file as well when doing

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: browser.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT})
  .then(tabs => browser.tabs.get(tabs[0].id))
  .then(tab => {
    console.info(tab);
  });
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for this

Comment: This did not work for me, I guess they restricted it since this answer? I now use messages instead.