# How to access to the tab object from popup script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to javascript and I want to code a firefox web extension.
I have a browser action button with a popup. but I didn't define the popup in the manifest, i set it in javascript code, because the click event won't be fired when the popup is defined. So here is the important part of my background script:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    var tabUrl = tab.url;
    browser.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "/popup/popup.html" });
    browser.browserAction.openPopup();   
    browser.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "" });
});
```

In this event the tab object is passed, so I can use the url.

This file is in the /background_scripts folder.
The popup is in the /popup folder. It's a html file with 2 menuitems. 
In the popup.js I have an event to get the click:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    if(e.target.id == menuItem1)
    {
    ...

    //here i want to use the url of the current tab    

});
```

How I can get the tab object or the url in my popup code?

The tabs.tab.getCurrent() method doesn't work as I understand according to this:

[tabs.getCurrent() result is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695817/tabs-getcurrent-result-is-undefined)

and this

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you use window.location.href?

Comment: After a bit of research i finally found the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41943267/6324114