# Firefox addon button (browser_action) not calling js on click

Tags: firefox-addon

Trying to create a simple addon to retry a duckduckgo search in google. It parses the current duckduckgo url search params, appends them to a google url, and opens that url in a new tab.

The searchGoogle.js works great when pasted directly into the console context of a duckduckgo search. And the addon loads correctly in about:debugging... But **I am unable to get the "searchGoogle.js" to fire on button (browser_action) click. What am I missing here?**

manifest.json

```
  {

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "SearchGoogle",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Repeats a duckduckgo search in a new tab using google.",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/48search-pointer-icon.png",
    "32": "icons/32search-pointer-icon.png",
    "16": "icons/16search-pointer-icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/48search-pointer-icon.png",
      "default_title": "SearchGoogle"
    },

  "background": {
      "scripts": ["searchGoogle.js"]
    }

}
```

searchGoogle.js

```
var myStr = window.location.href;
var googurl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
var params = getmyuri('q', myStr);
window.open(googurl+params, '_blank');
window.focus();
window.alert(googurl+params);

function getmyuri(n,s){
n = n.replace(/[\[]/,"\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\]");
var p = (new RegExp("[\\?&]"+n+"=([^&#]*)")).exec(s);
return (p===null) ? "" : p[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're currently doing is merely declaring a background script. A background script is loaded when the addon is loaded by the browser, but you need some code to react to other events.

Here's what I found in the MDN pages of [browser_action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action) :

> If you don't supply a popup, then a click event is dispatched to your extension's background scripts when the user clicks the button.
>   (...)
>   The extension's background scripts can receive click events when the user clicks the icon using code like this:
>   `browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){})`

So in your case, you need to wrap your "on click" code into this `browserAction.onClicked` event handler, something like this:

```
// searchGoogle.js

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  var myStr = window.location.href;
  var googurl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
  var params = getmyuri('q', myStr);
  window.open(googurl+params, '_blank');
  window.focus();
  window.alert(googurl+params);
});
```

And voilà, your code should be executed everytime you click the browserAction icon.

Comment: I want to mark it as the answer. But I'm still struggling to get it to fire.
*pulled out "window.alert(googurl+params);"
*tried different combinations of wrapping the function with the event listener.
*reloaded the extension in "about:debugging".
*checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/*browser_action to confirm my manifest is correct:
...
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/48search-pointer-icon.png",
      "default_title": "SearchGoogle"
    },

  "background": {
      "scripts": ["searchGoogle.js"]
    }
...

Comment: Did you try to replace your code with a simple `console.log` to check if the event was triggered properly? That's what I did and the event was triggered every time. I ask this because maybe operations such as window.open or alert might be unauthorized by default (this is only a supposition). But then this is a different issue.

Comment: Actually I just tried it, `window.alert` is not authorized in a background script, and `window.open` does not trigger any error but simply does nothing. Which makes sense since `window` does not really mean anything in a background script, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I pulled out the alert. It also makes sense now that `window` doesn't mean anything, what else would I use instead? I'm looking into `browser.windows.create({url: ""yourUrl""});` now...

Comment: It's firing now, marked your answer. Thank you. Now just trying to figure out why `browser.tabs.getCurrent();` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes here with the same question. Here are lessons observed:

1. `window.alert` is not a thing in a background script. Instead, wrap things in `console.log()`. [Logging to console from Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893981/logging-to-console-from-firefox-extension)
2. Event listeners can pass tab information already, see [tabs.getCurrent() result is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695817/tabs-getcurrent-result-is-undefined).
3. To fire on button click, DON'T supply a popup in the manifest, and DO wrap the code to be fired in `browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){})`.

Here's the final working script.

- Main stays the same.
- JS is:

  ```
  browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

      function getmyuri(n,s){
          n = n.replace(/[\[]/,"\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\]");
          var p = (new RegExp("[\\?&]"+n+"=([^&#]*)")).exec(s);
          return (p===null) ? "" : p[1];
      }

      console.log(tab)
      var googurl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
      var params = getmyuri('q', tab.url);
      browser.tabs.create({url: googurl+params});
  });
  ```